# Dropdowns work only after two clicks in Selenium web driver

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium

I am using Selenium with Python on the [Browserstack platform](http://www.browserstack.com).

I am testing a `select2` dropdown, and I always need to click the dropdown twice to make it work:

```
dropdown_click = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#s2id_autogen2 a.select2-choice')
actions.click(dropdown_click).perform()
actions.click(dropdown_click).perform()  # another click to open dropdown.
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
make_list = driver.find_element_by_id('select2-drop')
assert make_list.is_displayed()
```

There's `implicitly_wait`, but without the second `click()`, the dropdown is still invisible and assertion fails.

This is not the only JS dropdown that misbehaves this way for me in Selenium.

This JavaScript code works correctly in browsers, but in Selenium it's correct only when clicked the first time. The second time I have to call `click()` twice.

```
$('span.opener').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown-visible');
})
```

What's wrong with Selenium and these dropdowns?

**edit**: explicit waits did fix this problem.

Comment: Could you show the HTML code of the select dropdown, or share the link to the target web-site? Thanks.

Comment: could it be that select2 waits for the document and then performs its thing but selenium doesn't give select2 enough time to finish hence the click twice?  Try waiting before you do any clicking?

Comment: @getbuckts no, as I wrote, removing the second click makes it not work with `implicitly_wait`.

Comment: @culebrón implicit wait would not immediately wait, it is not a blocking operation. It just sets a timeout while finding an element, see [`Implicit waits`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#implicit-waits). You need to try wait [explicitly](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: @alecxe I guess this will do the trick. Testing this right now.

Comment: @culebrón please update us if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to hover to the dropdown first, then do your click operation. This helps me some times in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If it behaves like that using the statements below can work:

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("YourDropdownID"))).SelectByIndex(indexValueYouWantToSelct));
```

Or you can do this

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("YourDropdownID"))).SelectByText("YourDropDownItemText");
```

Or you can also try this

```
new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("YourDropdownID"))).SelectByValue("YourDoropDownItemValue");
```